# What is the withdrawals field of the response of web3.eth.getBlock()?

Tags: json-rpc, blocks, balances, shapella, withdrawal

I noticed that the withdrawal field has been added to the web3.eth.getBlock() response.  Here is a small example:

```
{
  <the usual fields>... ,
  withdrawals: [
    {
      index: '0x3812d',
      validatorIndex: '0x7ccdb',
      address: '0x04cc45cea9a1dbfe76f70cbfdfc42df76d188a8e',
      amount: '0xc7b080d'
    },
    {
      index: '0x3812e',
      validatorIndex: '0x7ccdc',
      address: '0x04cc45cea9a1dbfe76f70cbfdfc42df76d188a8e',
      amount: '0xc779298'
    }, <more of them>
  ],
  withdrawalsRoot: '0xa4cfd81611532f6692d87ba4a4d286c5f57191140c8f91ddacc7dbbf069d4f3c'
}
```

Is this due to the Shanghai update?
Is there any documentation on this somewhere?
I have read the [web3js doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.9.0/web3-eth.html#getblock). But there is no description about this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shapella upgrade](https://blog.ethereum.org/2023/03/28/shapella-mainnet-announcement) included a number of EIPs, including [EIP-4895: Beacon chain push withdrawals as operations](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4895).

> This EIP provides a way for validator withdrawals made on the beacon chain to enter into the EVM.

> Withdrawals are represented as a new type of object in the execution payload – an “operation” – that separates the withdrawals feature from user-level transactions.

The "execution payload" is what is returned by `web3.eth.getBlock()`.  It is called that way to distinguish it from Beacon Chain blocks.

The references for the withdrawal fields and a brief description are:

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4895#new-field-in-the-execution-payload-withdrawals

> The execution payload gains a new field for the withdrawals which is an RLP list of Withdrawal data.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4895#new-field-in-the-execution-payload-header-withdrawals-root

> The execution payload header gains a new field committing to the withdrawals in the execution payload.

> This commitment is constructed identically to the transactions root in the existing execution payload header by inserting each withdrawal into a Merkle-Patricia trie keyed by index in the list of withdrawals.

---

From EIP-4895, Withdrawal objects are serialized as a RLP list according to the schema: `[index, validator_index, address, amount]`.

EIP-4895 defines the items in the list as:

1. a monotonically increasing `index`, starting from 0, as a uint64 value that increments by 1 per withdrawal to uniquely identify each withdrawal
2. the `validator_index` of the validator, as a uint64 value, on the consensus layer the withdrawal corresponds to
3. a recipient for the withdrawn ether `address` as a 20-byte value
4. a nonzero `amount` of ether given in Gwei (1e9 wei) as a uint64 value.

---

When you are looking at an address and calculating its balance, you have to start looking at the withdrawals fields too, as the address could have received additional ether from a validator.  (Also important to know [What happens when a validator's withdrawal address is a smart contract with a fallback function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/what-happens-when-a-validators-withdrawal-address-is-a-smart-contract-with-a-fa))

Comment: Thank you for your clear summary. I'll read the docs.